# Crop out the surrounding white space of the image in the clipboard

Tags: windows-7, images, clipboard

I am looking for a program that can crop out the surrounding white space of the image in the clipboard. The resulting image should be placed in the clipboard. It should work on Microsoft Windows 7. Gratis is preferable.